# Trying to make irreversable operation in the quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit, unitarity

I want to make a 2 qubit circuit such that the non-unitary program will transform the regular basis in the way that:

$|0 0\rangle \to |00\rangle$

$|0 1\rangle \to |01\rangle$

$|10\rangle \to |01\rangle$ (the only one that affected)

$|11\rangle \to |11\rangle$

The only way I think of doing it, is after measuring the circuit I will change the classical outcomes so it will fit the transformation, for example in the classic way I would code:

```
if c[0]==1 & c[1]==0
       c[0]==0
       c[1]==1
```

but I didn`t find a way to write it in Qiskit language, please help.

Comment: Just hint: first q-bit of result is logical product (AND) of both input q-bits, second one is logical sum (OR) of both inputs. AND and OR can be implemented with Toffoli gate.

Comment: The use of "unreversible" and "ununitary" in your question is unusual.  All operations on a quantum circuit must be unitary, and therefore reversible.

Comment: @ChainedSymmetry: It bring to my mind one question: What about reset gate? Naturaly, it is not reversible operation. How does this fit to the concept of quantum computation?

Comment: @MartinVesely It's a good question, and DaftWullie gives a good answer [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3909/8623) (short answer, you have to take a measurement and possibly bit-flip).  I'm guessing this is not easy to implement in hardware, which is why it's only available in IBM Q simulations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to implement your transformation on IBM Q. Here is the result:
[image: Circuit]

Input is $|00\rangle$ in this case. You can set input values by application of $X$ gates on q-bits $|q0\rangle$ and $|q1\rangle$.

Please note that this circuit run on a simulator only as reset gate has not been implemented on real IBM Q quantum hardware. But it is possible to simply measure $|q2\rangle$ and $|q3\rangle$. In that case your transformation become reversible.

Comment: is that an image of a quantum circuit or quantum register and is there a textbook that shows how to read them with examples?

Comment: Initial state of a quantum register is on left hand side of the figure, a quantum circuit doing actual calculation (or quantum state transformation) follows. The right hand side of the figure contains measurement of the quantum register and record of the quantum state to a classic register.

Comment: See more inforation on how to read quantum circuits for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_circuit.

Comment: Why do you have q4 there not connected to anything?

Comment: @AHusain: I just used implicit configuration on IBM Q and there is always 5 qbits unless you say otherwise. Qbit q4 is of course not necessary for correct work of the circuit.